# C# datagridview - "column exceeds MaxLength Limit"

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview in main form that loads `Datetime` type of data into it. Unfortunately while I see data displayed correctly, system displays it as error

> column PlannedDate exceeds MaxLength limit

After googling a little bid, I've found solution by creating the event:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Control is TextBox)  // To clear the error in display of the cells
        {
            (e.Control as TextBox).MaxLength= 100;
        }
}
```

Problem is, this event is called on UPDATE of the form (i.e. when I add another row) but not on load, so while in the end everything works fine, user on start will be informed on error in columns...

Funny thing is, this problem started showing only when I had to migrate on Mac with windows on VirtualBox.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you just set the MaxLength in formload event of your form? or just set it manually in datagridview settings?